# Load pkl (using joblib or pickle) generates keyerror 120

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, joblib

I am trying to load a pkl file (in a windows machine) using joblib.
So my code is

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
output = joblib.load("file.pkl")
```

I get this error:

```
  File "cleaning.py", line 97, in <module>
output = joblib.load('file.pkl')
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1039, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
KeyError: 120
```

I tried also using pickle, in this way:

```
import pickle
with open('file.pkl', 'r') as input:
    output = pickle.load(input)
```

But I got this other error:

```
File "cleaning.py", line 94, in <module>
    output = pickle.load(input)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'x'.
```

Does anyone could help me?
I have already searched on stackoverflow but I didn't find any solution which works for me...
Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on a windows server 2008 / anaconda / python3.5 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading scikit-learn to 0.18.1.

```
pip install scikitlearn==0.18.1
```

This worked for me after upgrading from the default anaconda version (0.17).